# Data from oracle in utf-8 with php

Tags: php, oracle

i have a problem about getting data from oracle database. How to get data in utf-8? browser shows symbols with echo, but data from oracle has ? marks instead of letters

```
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
</head>
<?php

 $tns2 = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = sidname)))";
   if ($conn = oci_connect("user","pass", $tns2))
   {
       echo "YAY!";
       //oci_close($conn);
   }
   else
   {
       die("Nesiseka");
   }

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * rowname where rownum<=10');
oci_execute($stid);

oci_close($conn);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
echo"įęėšųį";
?>
```

Comment: `SELECT * rowname where rownum<=10` is not a valid oracle query.

Comment: what are your NLS_* session and database variables set with?

Comment: but everything works except data from oracle database I think is not in UTF-8

Comment: What is the database character set?  Are you correctly setting NLS_LANG environment variable?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Simple solution. Only add 'AL32UTF8' to line `if ($conn = oci_connect(username,pass, $tns2 , 'AL32UTF8'))` Everything works now.
Thank you for help

Comment: It's working with Oracle 11g but not with Oracle 10g. Any idea?

Comment: It also works with Oracle 10g. Check the [Globalization Support Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/applocaledata.htm#i635047) from Oracle.

Comment: Helped me with symfony 4 on an oracle database 12c, where the utf-8 chars didn't want to be displayed correctly in my twig templates

Comment: Saved my life after searching for hours what went wrong when querying the database with german special characters and results are missing.

Answer (score 5):

Use this to make database connection:

```
$conn = oci_connect(username,pass, $tns2 , 'AL32UTF8')
```

Answer (score 0):

set php encoding to utf 8

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

link for more
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

Comment: it is already set, echo"įęėšųį"; shows fine, but data from oracle databse is shown with ? instead of čęėšųū