# PHP built-in webserver ruins foreign characters

Tags: php, php-ini, php-builtin-server

I recently started using PHP's built-in webserver a lot more.

Unfortunately serving pages through it seems to have an effect on pages that retrieve data from our oracle database containing ÆØÅ.

The first image is when I run the script through Xampps' webserver, the second one is from PHP's built-in server.

[image: from xampp]
[image]

[image: from built-in]
[image]

The unpacked binary value of the 5th key can be seen next to each of the pictures.

Notice how it translates **Æ** into **ã†**. This obviously looks like an encoding error, but I'm not entirely sure what to look for. I'm not sure how exactly the built-in server serves pages, but I know the **difference** between Xampp and PHP is that they are using different PHP binaries and configuration.

Both php.ini files have `default_charset="UTF-8"` set.

Furthermore, looking at the response headers, both of them states: `Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Notice the `b""` ? It's binary literal. Please do the following, show the hexadecimal output of both fieldnames. Please do `echo unpack('C*', $fieldName);`.

Comment: Thanks for your input @DanFromGermany, I've added it. It's cler that their output is different, I'm just very confused where it's happening :/

Comment: Ok so, you see two different things but as the second output is represented as a binary literal, there is no bug and no difference. If you show the stuff in HTML, you should not have a difference. Its not advisable to use special characters in field names tho.

Comment: I agree that it's a bad practice, that's another department's responsibility, so I don't have much of a say. In terms of it not being a bug, it's troublesome when I'm trying to do $data['bemÆrkning'], and giving me an exception that they key doesn't exist.

Comment: Looking at it again very closely, the output of the unpack is different, to be exact, the 4th byte is not the same. Have you tried explicitly setting the [Oracle connection encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996077/data-from-oracle-in-utf-8-with-php)? Another thing is, you should be able to tell the other department when their stuff is bad practice and they should change it appropriately. Everything else is not professional.

Comment: Please also doublecheck which php.ini you are using, as on most platforms there is a seperate php.ini for the webserver sapi and the cli version. Also make sure the file itself is saved in UTF-8. I think you've done that, just double check to be sure.

Comment: As I know the binary string is already deprecated, so which version of php you are using?

Comment: And character **Æ** unicode value is U+00C6, and UTF-8 value should be **195 134**, so the second one is right. the binary sequence in the first picture **227 134 114** is not a valid UTF-8 character.

Comment: @shing nice additional input. The string he put in the question as text (not in the picture) `ÆØÅ` is different from the other two: `195 134 195 152 195 133`.